# How fast is geom.Point for pure data-storage?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, point

I'm going to need to store a large number of x/y-position pairs. Now I'm unsure about whether or not to use Flashs geom.Point-class for these, since performance will be important for my application, and I'm not gonna use any of the Point-class's methods. So I wonder if performance would benefit from me creating and using a custom class with just x and y properties, or if I could as well just use geom.Point without performance drop?

Or in other words: Does the pure existance of geom.Point's many methods (that I'm not gonna call) weigh down its instances?

Comment: I would take a step back and look at exactly why you need to store a cluster of points. There is a code smell floating about here and I can't quite point out the location.

Comment: Is that so? I'm going to have a lot of handmade paths that I want the DrawingAPI to draw later on. So I wrote all the coordinates for these paths into an XML-file, but as soon as I let Flash read that file, I'm going to need to store these paths someway. My intention was to do so in a Vector of Vectors of Points. How would you do it?

Comment: Why do you need to store them? You already have the data in the xml.

Comment: I would imagine that the vector of points would be a bit faster, but I don't think the speed improvement will be noticeable. Plus you already have an XML object with the data in it. Creating a vector to store the data will just cause redundancy that can in the future cause conflicts

Comment: Actually, I would probably go the vector route but not store just points. I would create a custom class that inherits from DisplayObject and store an instance for that in the vector. Since this is a DisplayObject it will have the x and y already as an attribute that can be overridden when needed.

Comment: I would like to store them for readability and object-orientation. As each path belongs to a specific object, I'd like these objects to have a Vector of their respective path-points as a property.
Hm, but maybe you are right and I'd better just pass these objects a reference to the xml, so they can get and return their path-points directly from XML once asked for?

Comment: Well I think there should be some kind of list of "paths" (dictionary, vector, array, arraycolelction). but I think that this list should be of a custom displayObject. The only real problem I can see with this method is that the data in the XML is no longer coupled to the display object, and when it becomes time to access the data in the xml it could possible be invalid. So you will have to make sure the reference to the xml data is updated when the custom displayobject instance is updated.

Comment: Wouldn't a custom displayObject have too much overhead as well when I just need x and y properties? I'm afraid I don't really see the reason to extend displayObject, yet.

Comment: If i understand correctly the X and Y are already being used for a display object somewhere(Sprite or a MovieClip probably). You could be storing those instances in the list but instead do mySprite extends Sprite override X and Y setter/getter and update XML when those values change.

Answer (score 0):

It would most certainly be quicker creating a small class to store x and y values as the overhead from the Point class will have an effect on the speed of the program.  By writing your own class you can also take advantage of writing your own functions to handle simple data manupulation (adding/subtracting/multiplying) rather than having to do `x1 + x2` and `y1 + y2`.

For an example try making a blank project with nothing but a timer and a loop and time how long it takes to create 10 million (for example) `Point`s and store them in an array, and how long it takes to create 10 million of your own class with only x and y member variables.

Comment: Thank you :) ! But hearing you talking about "10 million Points" I wonder if say just a thousend Points would already cause performance-weight enough to justify a custom class?

Comment: creating 10 million instances is a moot point since this is only done once.

Comment: creating 10 million point objects take 2371 milliseconds on my machine. creating 10 million custom objects that behave like the point class takes 2123 milliseconds on this machine. I fail to see how 248 milliseconds speed increase on 10 million objects is worth noting

Comment: @The_asMan What is the memory consumption difference? I doubt it would be significant, I'm just curious.

Comment: Great! Thank you for doing this experiment!

Comment: if you are really worried about performance, I would imagine a `Vector.<Number>` would be the fastest, where x,y pairs are stored in even and odd elements.

Comment: but i also wouldn't worry about performance until I profiled and saw that it was actually a problem

Comment: @32bitkid I didn't profile the test, but the Point inherits from object as does a custom class, so the inheritance chain is identical and I would imagine that the memory overhead would be very close. Without looking at the code for the Point class I would bet that the reason it is slightly faster is there might be some overhead in the constructor of the Point class that I ignored in my test class.

Comment: @32bitkid The odd even concept is a neat idea though.